# Why is arrow notation for yield deprecated?

Tags: syntax, f#

I'm reading through a pretty swell wikibook on F#. At the bottom of the [section on List Comprehensions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists#Using_List_Comprehensions), it explains that one can use an arrow operator instead of the yield/yield! keywords. But it notes that this is deprecated. I was wondering why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not deprecated as such - at least [Visual F# 2010 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209(VS.100).aspx) on MSDN still uses it. What was deprecated is some other syntax, which included `->` and `->>` in places other than simple `for` expressions. In particular, see [this post by Don Syme](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2008/08/29/detailed-release-notes-for-the-f-september-2008-ctp-release.aspx) - quote:

> `>` and `->>` are now deprecated except in the compact sequence expressions.
>
> The two shorthands `->` and `->>` are now deprecated **except in the sequence expression short form**: `seq { for x in c -> f(x) }`. In all other sequence expressions, use the full names `yield` and `yield!`.

Answer (score 3):

I think removing most uses of -> and ->> was done for consistency with C#.  Personally, I think this is a mistake.

Haskell comprehensions are powerful partly because they are so succinct, just like set notation - the F# syntax ends up making things harder to understand because anything relatively complicated ends up being split over many lines.